# How do i link the data of 2 tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 tables , Generator and Result.

Generator has_many results
result belongs_to generator

How can i have a page whereby i can display all the values of generators and the result ? In my Result Controller create must i link the Generator_id ? I've tried but it's giving me an error whenver i'm trying to create a new result belonging to that generator.

For example localhost:3000/generator/3/results/new , after clicking create , it gives me the following error:

`Couldn't find Generator without an ID .`

I've received few suggestion asking me to create a new controller to do so. If so how should i pass my @generator and @result to it ?

## GeneratorController

```
def index
    @generators = Generator.all(:include => [:results])
  end

def create    
    @generator = Generator.new(generator_params)
    @generator.choice = params[:choice]
      if params[:choice] == 'Randomly'
          @generator.random_generate(generator_params)
      elsif params[:choice] == 'No_of_ATGC'
          @generator.no_ATGC(params[:no_A],params[:no_T],params[:no_G],params[:no_C])
      elsif params[:choice] == 'Seating'
          @generator.seating(params[:user_seq])
      end

    @generator.result_choice=params[:result_choice]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @generator.save
          if @generator.result_choice == 'Yes'
            format.html { redirect_to(new_generator_result_path(@generator)) }
          else
            format.html { redirect_to @generator, notice: 'Result was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @generator }
          end
      else 
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @generator.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

## Result model

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :ncbi_ref_seq,:genome_seq, :genome_sample
   belongs_to :generator, foreign_key: "generator_id"

    def generate_result(result_params)
    ref_seq = self.ncbi_ref_seq
    Bio::NCBI.default_email = "spykix@hotmail.com"
    fasta_sequence = Bio::NCBI::REST::EFetch.nucleotide(ref_seq,"fasta")
    fasta=Bio::FastaFormat.new(fasta_sequence)
    self.genome_seq = fasta.data
    self.genome_sample = fasta.definition    

    g=Generator.last
    p=self.genome_seq.scan(g.c_primer)
    self.binding_times= p.length()      
  end

end
```

## ResultContorller

```
def index
    @results = Result.all(:include => :generator)
  end

def create
    @result = Result.new
    @result = @result.generate_result(result_params)
    @generator = Generator.find(params[:id])
    @result = generator.results.build(result_params)

   respond_to do |format|
      if @result.save
        format.html { redirect_to @result, notice: 'Result was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @result }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @result.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: kindly ,can you paste some code of your models and controllers ..the problems seems in your controller ..and where do you want to display these data ?

Comment: i've pasted it. I want to display these datas in generator index form where i can show all the genarator values and all the results belonging to that generator.

Comment: I'm a bit confused... it seems you're not quite following the "Rails way" of doing things. You shouldn't be showing the values of *all* generators on your generator form. The values of all generators should go on the index page.

Comment: my actual code in the Generator controller index is just ` @generator = Generator.all` but i want this generator/index page to display all the generators and their results as well.

Comment: because later on, i'll have another table call user and each user can view whatever generator data they have and from there they analyze their results n etc... this is why i need to have a page whereby i have all the values of generators + the results together .

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a variable in the controller like this:

```
@generators = Generator.all
```

Then in your view...

```
<% @generators.each do |g| %>
  <% g.results.each do |r| %>
    <% debug r %>   
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It sounds like whatever code you're using to try to pull out all of your generators isn't correct.

Comment: hi i've tried this method. g.results.ncbi_ref_seq but i get undefined method ncbi_ref_seq . NCBI_ref_seq is an attribute belonging to the results. It's 1 of the data i want to show in m page

Comment: Well, `g.results` is probably an *array*, not a single model. You probably have to have another loop that iterates through your results if you want to show some part of it. I'll update my answer given your response, but this seems like another question...

Comment: aardvarkk : The value of the results are all empty. But when i go into locahost:3000/results , they're there.... i followed ur method but they're not shown in locahost:3000/generators

Comment: `def create
    generator = Generator.find(params[:generator])
    result = Result.new(result_params)
    result.generate_result(result_params)
    @result = generator.results.build(result_params) `

when i have this , i get an error couldn't fine generator without an ID. if my resultcontroller index code is

Comment: `def create
    @result = Result.new(result_params)
    @result.generate_result(result_params)
end`

This works fine but then in in the view, i can't get the value of Results. They're all null. I tried running this in concole Result.find(1) n it gives me generator_id = nil. How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to implement nested resources http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

You need to modify your routes to something like this

```
  resources :generators do
    resources :results
  end
```

This way you have the generator_id, so you can modify you controller code to something like this:

```
  generator = Generator.find(params[generator_id])
  generator.results.build(result_params)
```

Comment: My routes is as what u typed. But i still get the error message =(... Before i proceed to generator.results.build(result_params) i need to have the result_params. I get the values by doing some function defined in my model. erm the original code for Result `def create` - `@result = Result.new ` `@result = @result.generate_result`

Comment: You form_for looks like form_for [@generator, @result]

Comment: Where is your post request going to? post /generators/:generator_id/results

Comment: ? what do u mean where is the post request going to ? i mean how can i know where is the request going ? o.o

Comment: If you are running rails server, after press your "create" button (aka when the error occur) in your console/terminal/shell Did you see `Started POST /results` or (by example) `Started POST /generators/1/results`  ?

Comment: yes i do. i get generators/1/results/new and after clicking create for this form again i get the value n etc... but now i want to have a page whereby i can view the data for all generators and the results generated using all those generators

Comment: hooo, sorry I misundestand the question